# Chrome debugging port not open after 10 seconds

Tags: r

I am using following code: It works good on local system and one unix server, but fails on another server. Any idea what I might need to do

```
    > library(chromote)
    > set_default_chromote_object(
       Chromote$new(browser = Chrome$new(args = "--no-sandbox"))
```

and I am getting following error:

> Chrome debugging port not open after 10 seconds.

Comment: It seems there is an issue happening within the `tryCatch` [here](https://github.com/rstudio/chromote/blob/ba9bffc291be468c48e658f95fa2bc952a1dbff5/R/chrome.R#L84-L110). I'm not very familiar with `chromote` so I can't offer much support, but it seems likely there is an issue arising from one of the `if` statements within the `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you can check:

1. On the server in question, start chrome and go to `chrome://version/` . Search the *Command Line:* section and make sure `--enable-logging` is in there.
2. Strat R on the server in question, and do:

```r
library(chromote)
debug(chromote:::launch_chrome)
```

Now run that R-code in as normal and when it stops and waits for input, hit `n` and then enter and repeat hitting enter until you get to the lines you link to on github. After line `87` when output gets defined, type `output` on the terinal and hit enter. Inspect the output and make sure that it actually conatins the lines `DevTools listening on ws://` . If it does not, see if there are other ways that logging text identifies the port it listens to. If so, I would git clone that package, go in and change the way it discovers the port number and modify the package that runs for that server.

### Running Chrome without X server

There are two viable options here:

1. vnc
2. X.org dummy driver

Here is the VNC recipe:

#### 1: VNC

a. `sudo dnf install tigervnc-server` (for centos 8), `sudo yum install tigervnc-server` (for centos 7)
b. vncserver :1 (or some other suitable number)
c. DISPLAY=:1 R # and run R code to launch chrome etc.

Now you can connect from your client and see that chrome runs as it should:

```
vncviewer centos.ip.address:1
```

#### 2: X.org dummy

I have never done this myself, but in theory it should be straight forward if you read docs and follow a tutorial.

Comment: It is centos unix and doesnt have X display. Would it matter, because when I tried to do "chromium-browser --remote-debuggin-port=9222", I got error that "unable to open X display"

Comment: That's a problem. I often use vnc for this, though they have made it harder by removing the vncserver script from the dist. Can you make chrome run by `ssh -X` into the server? Of that works, and chrome starts, then you can look at ways to run it without, using something appropriate

Comment: It is using a port which is not open and we dont want to randomly open it as it is production. Not sure what else can I do

Comment: you can ssh in and port forward, `ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901` , then you run `vncserver :1` on the server and now from your workstation you can `vncviewer lcoalhost:1` - now forwarding your connection over ssh to the server (which is as safe as ssh is)